# how to apply a function that returns all data combinations

Tags: r

I have this `data.frame`:

```
df <- data.frame(group=c(rep("group1",12), rep("group2",12)),
                 variable=c(rep("var1",4), rep("var2",4), rep("var3",4)),
                 value=sample(24))
```

I would like to apply a function, say, mean. So I can get a matrix (2 x 3) with means for each group at each variable.

I have tried with `tapply`, but it does not return what I need. Is there another approach using the apply functions?

thanks

Comment: how did you use tapply? `with(dat, tapply(value, list(group, variable), mean))` gives me a 2x3 matrix

Comment: Next time use `set.seed`, because as you can see, everyone gave different outputs because of `sample`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tapply does work, and provides easiest code:

```
with(df, tapply(value, list(group,variable), mean))
       var1 var2 var3
group1  8.5 14.0   14
group2  8.0 18.5   12
```

Answer (score 1):

use ddply from the plyr package

```
require(plyr)
ddply(df, .(group, variable), summarize, m=mean(value))
```

gives

```
   group variable     m
1 group1     var1 15.00
2 group1     var2  9.25
3 group1     var3 13.50
4 group2     var1  6.50
5 group2     var2 20.00
6 group2     var3 10.75
```

you can reshape this

```
reshape(res, idvar="group", timevar="variable", direction="wide")
```

and obtain

```
   group m.var1 m.var2 m.var3
1 group1   15.0   9.25  13.50
4 group2    6.5  20.00  10.75
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with @rawr's answer in the comments. Here's an alternate way with `by`:

```
rbind(by(df, list(df$group, df$variable), function(x) { mean(x$value) }))

##         var1  var2 var3
## group1 13.75 16.50   14
## group2  9.50  8.25   13
```

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, group ~ variable,  value.var = "value", fun.aggregate = mean)

##    group  var1 var2  var3
## 1 group1 12.25 12.5 10.25
## 2 group2 17.25 10.5 12.25
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(group, variable) %>%
  summarize(meanValue = mean(value)) %>%
  spread(variable, meanValue)
#Source: local data frame [2 x 4]
#
#   group  var1 var2  var3
#1 group1 17.25 9.75 14.25
#2 group2 16.00 4.75 13.00
```